# UINavigationController hide bars when keyboard appears crashes app (SWIFT)

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, navigationbar

I am using several storyboards to present my views to the user. The storyboards all open with a `UINavigationController` which embeds the views necessary.

To choose the the corresponding storyboard for the user i run some logic within the AppDelegate and then load the storyboard.

AppDelegate

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    let storyboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let navigationController:UINavigationController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as UINavigationController
    let rootViewController:UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Initial") as UIViewController
    navigationController.viewControllers = [rootViewController]
    self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
}
```

Everything runs smoothly. If I however tick the option, that the `UINavigationController` should hide the bar when a keyboard appears (using an `UITextField`), the app crashes. However only in iOS 8. iOS 7 runs smoothly.

Hide the navbar when keyboard appears

[image: shows the option to hide the navbar when keyboard appears]

This is the error i get:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[OS_dispatch_queue _hideForKeyboardAppearance]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15d67540'
```

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

I am guessing that the delegation is somehow messed up because of the way I load the storyboards. If i hide the navbar by hand via

```
@IBAction func editTextFieldStart(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
}
```

everything works out ok. I am just curious to why it does not work the other way.

Answer (score 0):

It should be the other way around. Apple says in its documentation that this property is only available for iOS (8.0 and later).

Comment: Ashraf: I just retested. On Iphone 4 its runs just fine, Iphone 5 with iOS 8 it crashes. Very odd.

Comment: Can you double-check those iOS versions? The error you're seeing really does point to what @Ashraf is pointing out.

Comment: Sure. The Iphone4 runs on 7.1.2. The other device, the iPhone 5 runs on 8.1.3. The code crashes on the iPhone 5. I could built a small test projects, which narrows it down to my very problem and upload it.